# dotnet ef Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

In angular + asp.net core 3.1 project, I am getting this error, whenever I try to access anything related to EF.

dotnet ef
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH

Everything was working fine before. Due to some error I downloaded my old package of the project from GitHub and pasted, and now getting this error.

I have already set environment variables too

[Error in dotnet CLI + .csproj file setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgoMB.jpg)

[My environmental variable set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UymO4.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRbVN.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is resolved when we open VS code in admin mode.